# How do I import a sketchfab model into 2.82

Tags: texturing, import, dae

When you download a model from sketchfab it saves as a .zip file with a folder for texture as .pngs and a folder for the model as a .fbx file. How do I import the model with the textures into blender? I don't care if I need to convert or even how long it takes, I just need a solution.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541